# Drawer Navigator render below status bar (margin top) [React Navigation]

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation and I have a DrawerNavigator and I want the drawer to be below the status bar. This is an example:

[image]

In the drawer configuration I have setted a `contentComponent` with a View inside, I tried changing the view height, margin, top, etc por the View is actually inside the drawer so it doesn't affect the white box.

Comment: try this https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/843

Comment: Tried but didn't work, though I think he wanted it to be on top of the status bar, I want it to be below.

Answer (score 0):

I know It's late now but may some others can take benefit from this.

`<DrawerContentScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={{paddingTop: 10}}>`

*contentContainerStyle* property has by default some paddingTop so you can over right.

Thanks